# How should I divide my free disk space to setup (swap for) Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, system-installation, swap

I failed to setup the latest version of Ubuntu. During setup a message appeared that the creation of swap has been failed. How should I divide my free space for setting up Ubuntu (50GB free space, my RAM is 8GB)?

Comment: The sizes to allocate depend upon what you want/plan to do with it. the version of ubuntu is useful.  your tags say 16.04; but wording implies latest (stable) which is 17.04.  17.04 can use a swapfile (its default); but if upgrading it can use a swap partition; 16.04 however wants a a swap partition  (it can be disabled after install).   Depending on your use; you could disable swap (I do on a x86 tablet to increase ssd life).  Are you using the latest Ubuntu LTS or latest standard Ubuntu release as they differ in swap file/partitioning ?

Comment: I have got the ubuntu 16.04 which I try to install it ,I want to know the exact space for swap and for home?
  (My lap lenovo has ram 8GB and hard 1 tera  )   
Also Windows 10 was installed on my lap before I try to get ubuntu now I lost it which I have to do first put Windows then ubuntu or the opposite?

Comment: I'd recommend having partitions for /home (your data), / (system) and swap.  the reason for a separate /home is its safer for re-installs as you can format the system but leave your data (in /home) intact.   Ubuntu does a good job at avoiding this; but other distros do not; allowing you to switch should you want to.   The size for / has already been suggested as 50gb; myself I'd say 20-32gb should be fine - but the amount of programs/apps/desktops/... you'll install will dictate here, as upgrades to later versions need install-space, so 50gb is reasonable

Comment: space for swap; it can be small as already suggested providing you don't want to hibernate (which has lost popularity anyway - most people seem to just sleep their systems).  if you want to hibernate; your should have swapspace.used + total_memory; which means if you usually use 1gb swap; +8gb ram =9gb allowing the 1gb used & all 8gbs of ram to bet written to swap before hibernating.  your usage will dictate the size you need.  size of /home also should be dictated by what data you need/want to store etc; usually more than / (root or system partition)

Answer (score 0):

I installed Ubuntu multiple time on multiple devices.
and every time I installed Ubuntu on 50 GB free space and made 1GB for swap.
while I install Ubuntu I manually divide my hard drive to get the best specification and settings for me making two partitions one for SWAP and the other for Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you tell me the exact space for ubuntu ,swap and for home ?

Comment: Also  Windows 10 was  installed on my lap before I try to get ubuntu now I lost it which I have  to do first put Windows then ubuntu or the opposite?                               Wattting  ^_^

Comment: @HendMohammed I can tell you for sure my current device hard disk partitioning which is. 1GB of swap, and 65GB for Ubuntu (home is included in the same partition) and the rest of my 500GB hard is divided as I wish for my data.
the best way to do it (at least for me) is to install windows then Ubuntu that way you will be able to boot to GRUB which is (also for me :-D ) way better than Windows boot loader. If you need anything else I'll be waiting.